# Source path of CallStack is invalid when debugging with CMake in VSCode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gcc, cmake

I'm building a debugging environment with CMake in VSCode.
Debugging with breakpoints works fine in Visual Studio using the same CMake.
However, in VSCode, the target source file of CallStack is not normal.

The location of the source file is shown below.

`C:/Workspace/CPU_Raytracing/main.cpp`

The output in the Debug console is shown below.

```
Thread 1 "Renderer_Tester" hit Breakpoint 2, main () at C:/Workspace/CPU_Raytracing/main.cpp:7
7 in C:/Workspace/CPU_Raytracing/main.cpp
```

However, the path obtained from CallStack via Copy Call Stack is shown below.

`main() (c:\Workspace\CPU_Raytracing\build\C\Workspace\CPU_Raytracing\main.cpp:7)`

Does anyone have a solution for this situation?

Thanks in advance.

---

The same goes for clearing CMake's cache, or removing the buildfolder and restarting it.

Debugging using BreakPoint with a CMake Project in Visual Studio worked fine.

The desired result is that when debugging via CMake from VSCode, it stops at the BreakPoint and points to the corresponding SourceCode.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

The problem was that I tried to fix the situation by modifying the options in tasks.json, launch.json, and c_cpp_properties.json like other debugging methods, not cmake.

Setting "cmake.debugConfig" in settings.json solved the problem.

Here are the options I used

```
"cmake.debugConfig": {
    "type": "cppdbg",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "CMake Debug",
    "program": "${command:cmake.launchTargetPath}",
    "args": [],
    "stopAtEntry": false,
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "environment": [],
    "externalConsole": false,
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "C:/cygwin64/bin/gdb.exe",
}
```